# Xcode static analyser & memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Thanks for stopping by.

this static analyser warning is annoying me 
here is my code

```
+ (INURLConnection*)createConnectionForRequest:(INHTTPRequest *)aRequest {

    INURLConnection* result = [[INURLConnection alloc] init];
    if(result){
        result.request = aRequest;
        result.error = nil;
    }
    return result;
}
```

the "return result" line is showing me the potential memory leak warning (when i use analyser). This is a create method, the methods that consumes looks like this

```
INURLConnection *connection_tmp = [INURLConnection createConnectionForRequest:aRequest];
self.connection = connection_tmp, [connection_tmp release];
```

so the create connection returns with retain count of 1,
self.connection increases the retain count, and also there is a release.

i know i can use ARC, but i want to know why the static analyser is showing potential memory leak here.

Is it safe to ignore this warning?

cheers
Arun

Comment: @borrrden yes, the naming convention was wrong, i renamed the function then the warning gone, so now it stick to the rules.


@ tim Potter thanks for the answers. I do need to autorelease if i do not follow the naming convention.

i got myself confused with the CFCreatefunctions.


cheers
Arun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not safe to ignore this warning because you are violating one of the "rules" of Cocoa memory management: "You Don’t Own Objects Returned by Reference".

Change the last line of your function to

```
return [result autorelease];
```

and the Xcode warning should go away.

You should read Apple's documentation on the subject, [Basic Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), which go in to the various conventions in a bit more detail. It's good to stick to these rules as anyone else reading or using your code will expect it to behave that way.

Comment: However, if you rename the method to be `newConnectionForRequest` then it follows the naming conventions mentioned in the document you offered, and the warning should disappear as the analyzer now expects the method to return a +1 object.